# libinput-gestures two-finger swipe?

Tags: arch-linux, gnome3, wayland, libinput, mouse-gestures

I run arch on a macbook, still dual-booting into macos from time to time.

The hardest thing I've hade to re-train muscle memory wise is the "swipe right to go back in the browser"-feature from macos.

In order to get that functionality in linux as well I've installed `libinput-gestures` and configured `~/.config/libinput-gestures.conf` with:

```
gesture swipe left 3    xdotool key alt+Right
gesture swipe right 3   xdotool key alt+Left
```

While that seem to work I would prefer to be able to change the `3` to a `2`. But from my experience that does not seem to work.

Why is 2-finger swipe a no-go? Is there a work-around? I'm using gnome3 under wayland.

Answer (score 1):

I apparently can't even get the 3 finger swipe to work on Ubuntu 16.10 with Unity on Mir, but I have a *hunch* at why this isn't working for you.

By default, touchpad drivers enable the "Horizontal scrolling" feature -- either Edge or Two-Finger. Since Mac touchpads don't have the same Edge detection as some PC touchpads, Two-Finger is probably enabled by default.

To disable Two-Finger horizontal scrolling*, open GNOME's Mouse settings panel and switch to the "Touchpad" tab. Then, uncheck "Enable horizontal scrolling" or "Enable two-finger horizontal scrolling" or so, and try the `libinput-gestures` config mentioned in the question again.

* This is undoubtedly configurable through `gsettings` / `dconf` but I can't find it.

Comment: I like your hunch, though disabling two finger scrolling and horizontal scrolling didn't help. In fact, adding 2-finger swipe configuration lines to `~/.config/libinput-gestures.conf` stopped horizontal scrolling altogether, even though they were ineffective.